# Google Script Run never executed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-apps-script-addon

I am trying to create a simple addon in Google Docs, but after reading the documentation I cannot figure out how it is possible that google.script.run doesn't work properly.
Here is my base code:

code.gs

```
function onOpen(e) {
  DocumentApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
      .addItem('Start', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi();
}

function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
}

function showSidebar() {
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('sidebar')
      .setTitle('NeuralText');
  DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}

function dummyFunc(){
  var doc_id = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId();
  Logger.log(doc_id);
  return doc_id;
}
```

sidebar.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
    <!-- The CSS package above applies Google styling to buttons and other elements. -->

    <style>
    .branding-below {
      bottom: 56px;
      top: 0;
    }
    .branding-text {
      left: 7px;
      position: relative;
      top: 3px;
    }
    .col-contain {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .col-one {
      float: left;
      width: 50%;
    }
    .logo {
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .radio-spacer {
      height: 20px;
    }
    .width-100 {
      width: 100%;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="sidebar branding-below">
    <div class="output"></div>
      <form>
        <div class="block form-group">
          <label for="translated-text"><b>Insert URL</b></label>
          <input class="width-100" id="shared-brief"/>
        </div>
        <div class="block" id="button-bar">
          <button class="blue" id="test-btn">Test</button>
        </div>
      </form>
      
    </div>

    <div class="sidebar bottom">
      <img alt="Add-on logo" class="logo" src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/product/1x/translate_48dp.png" width="27" height="27">
      <span class="gray branding-text">Translate sample by Google</span>
    </div>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $('#test-btn').click(printTest);
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
            .withFailureHandler(showError).dummyFunc();
      });

      function printTest() {
        console.log('test');
      }

      function showError() {
       console.log('error')
      }

      function onSuccess() {
        console.log('success')
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

appsscript.json

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Paris",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui",
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents",
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
}
```

If I am in the editor and run `dummyFunc`, I can see in Log the ID of the Doc. But if I test my addon I keep getting 'error' from the client-side function showError.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Under which configuraiton do you test the Addon? What Apps Script runtime are you using?

Comment: It works for me

Comment: I was able to get this working simply disabling the new V8 engine.

Comment: It must be related to [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/149114362) bug

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make this working simply disabling the new V8 runtime.
Really strange behavior and, above all, completely undocumented.